# Using Moq to modify the argument to a stubbed void method

Tags: c#, moq, void

I have a bit of a perfect storm that's preventing me from testing a class. The class is a `RestClient` that's wrapping an in-house `HttpClient` (which I cannot modify). The `ExecuteMethod` method on the `HttpClient` is void. It accepts an `IHttpMethod`, and it modifies this object based on the response from the server. I want to mock out `ExecuteMethod` so that it modifies the `IHttpMethod` for me. I'm trying to use `Callback` to achieve this, but it's not working.

Here's the code that sends the request:

```
var httpClient = this.httpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient();
httpClient.ExecuteMethod(method);

var response = this.GetResourceResponse<T>(method.ResponseBodyAsStream.AsString());
response.ResponseHeaders = method.ResponseHeaders;
response.Status = method.StatusCode.ToString();
response.StatusCode = (int)method.StatusCode;

return response;
```

And here's my attempt at mocking:

```
var mockHttpMethod = new Mock<IHttpMethod>();
mockHttpMethod.Setup(m => m.ResponseBodyAsStream).Returns(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foo")));

var modifyHttpMethod = new Action<IHttpMethod>(m =>
{
    m = mockHttpMethod.Object;
});

var mockHttpClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
mockHttpClient.Setup(c => c.ExecuteMethod(It.IsAny<IHttpMethod>()))
    .Callback<IHttpMethod>(modifyHttpMethod);

var mockHttpClientFactory = new Mock<ILegalHoldHttpClientFactory>();
mockHttpClientFactory.Setup(f => f.CreateHttpClient()).Returns(mockHttpClient.Object);

var restClient = new RestClient(mockHttpClientFactory.Object);
```

When the `modifyHttpMethod` action is executed, I observe two things, both of which I expect:

1. The incoming `IHttpMethod` (`m`) has the properties I expect it to have.
2. After assigning the mock object to `m`, it contains the stubbed values that I setup in my test.

However, after the callback is executed and control is returned to my application code, my `method` variable still has its old values that I saw in step 1 above, which causes a null reference exception when trying to read `method.ResponseBodyAsStream`.

Is what I'm trying to do even achievable? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replicated your setup vis a vis mocking, and can't find any issues with it:

```
public interface IHttpMethod
{
    MemoryStream ResponseBodyAsStream { get; set; }
}

public interface IHttpClient
{
    void ExecuteMethod(IHttpMethod method);
}

public class HttpClient : IHttpClient
{

    #region IHttpClient Members

    public void ExecuteMethod(IHttpMethod method)
    {

    }

    #endregion
}

public class Factory
{
    public virtual IHttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        return new HttpClient();
    }
}

public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private readonly Factory _factory;

    public ClassUnderTest(Factory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public string GetResponseAsString(IHttpMethod method)
    {
        var myClient = _factory.CreateHttpClient();
        myClient.ExecuteMethod(method);

        return method.ResponseBodyAsStream.ToString();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ScratchPadTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SampleTest()
    {
        var mockHttpMethod = new Mock<IHttpMethod>();
        mockHttpMethod.Setup(x => x.ResponseBodyAsStream).Returns(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("foo")));

        var modifyHttpMethod = new Action<IHttpMethod>(m =>
        {
            m = mockHttpMethod.Object;
        });

        var mockHttpClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();
        mockHttpClient.Setup(c => c.ExecuteMethod(It.IsAny<IHttpMethod>())).Callback<IHttpMethod>(modifyHttpMethod);

        var myFactoryStub = new Mock<Factory>();
        myFactoryStub.Setup(f => f.CreateHttpClient()).Returns(mockHttpClient.Object);

        var myCut = new ClassUnderTest(myFactoryStub.Object);

        Assert.IsNotNull(myCut.GetResponseAsString(mockHttpMethod.Object));
    }

}
```

That test passes, meaning that the memory stream is not null (otherwise an exception would be generated).  The only X factor that I can see is your AsString() extension method (I'm assuming that's an extension method as intellisense doesn't show it to me on MemoryStream).  Could your problem be in there?

And, by the way, what you're trying to do is almost certainly achievable with Moq.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the extension method. I could see how the extension method might read the stream and close it, making it unavailable, but the stream is actually unavailable before the AsString() method is even executed. I'm not sure why your code works and my doesn't. I wound up doing some refactoring to make this more testable, so this is no longer an issue, but I'd still like to get it to work, as it seems like a useful technique. Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: No problem -- if you've got a more testable method, that's always good.  :)  What I'd take away, though, is that I'm pretty sure you could have accomplished what you wanted to with Moq somehow or another.  Sometimes it's not easy to get there, but it's pretty flexible.